# error on wordpress front-end submission file upload

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I have a function working for wordpress front-end forms except for one thing. I can upload images from the front-end form but if I opt NOT to add a file, I get the following error:

Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in wp-includes/post.php on line 4365

Here is the code that handles the image upload part:

```
if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
  $newupload = insert_attachment($file, $pid);
  }
}

function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

Note: This only happens when file is not uploaded. Seems like it's expecting an integer and throws an error if there is not file id or integer. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when I went from my local server to a staging server, the error disappeared. Guessing that it might be a wp-config or htaccess file difference that caused the error, not sure, but anyway it's no longer an issue.